# Nikon Lens format for D5100

Tags: lens, nikon, nikon-d5100

I'm planning to buy the Nikon D5100. As I'll also buy a 200mm lens which format to go for ? And what does they mean and their differences [**DX Format FX Format CX Format**]

Comment: The only difference is the addition of the "CX" format, which are lenses for the Nikon 1 (1" sensor) system.

Comment: Good point, Stan. CX lenses won't work; the other question answers the rest.

Answer (score 0):

For Nikon DSLRs you'll want to get an F-Mount lens.  Both DX and FX lenses are F-Mount.  The new CX lenses are not.  The D5100 has a DX format sensor, but FX lenses will still work.  The D5100 doesn't have an internal focus motor, so if you want auto-focus to work you will need an AF-S lens, which has the motor in the lens itself.